# (If) statement not working when including it from another php file

Tags: php, if-statement, include

I have two php files first is `sample.php` and the second is `if.php`. I have some code written in `sample.php` basically declaration of two variables and an `else` statement. I have the `if` statement in `if.php` file which I'm including before `else` statement. But on running my code its shows an error:

> Unexpected 'else'...etc.

Can you please help me figuring out what is wrong with the code?

**Sample.php**

```
<?php
$a=10;
$b=20;

include 'if.php';
else
{
echo $b.' is greater';
}
?>
```

**if.php**

```
<?php
if($a>$b)
{
echo $a.' is greater';
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that you cannot execute a if / else logic like this. Also, why? Why not just write the if sentence with the else?

Comment: @Epodax he has shown his code for if.php in the second half.

Comment: if.php is right on the bottom of my question.. and i don't know if i can do this or can't.. but what if i have to???

Comment: So he has, my bad - It's still early and I haven't had my coffee :)

Comment: How do you even come to such ideas?

Comment: I don't think there will ever be a case where you "have to", not with if / else logic. or any code in general, a include / require is really only keeping code separated, either for maintainability (and / or general structure). - I get what you are trying to do, I just don't think it's ever gonna be useful (and / or) needed.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve would be better served as a function I think. I should stress *I think* though. It's not clear why you would want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
include 'if.php';
else
```

Nice, there is no such thing as `include`  `else`. Even if you have an `if` clause at the end of your included file, the `include` line breaks its sequence.

`else` can only come after either an `if` or an `else if` block, no third option. Period.

Here is how PHP parser will see your 2 files

```
if($a>$b){
  echo $a.' is greater';
}
include "if.php";
else {
  echo 'na';
}
```

Which is clearly invalid.

If you still want to keep things as they are, like you mentioned in the comments. You can do 1 small trick (amongst many other methods). Make your `else` another `if` which is contrary to the first `if`. Like

**if.php**

```
if($a>$b){
  echo $a.' is greater';
}
```

**main file**

```
include "if.php";
if($a<=$b) {
  echo 'na';
}
```

Comment: actually i have two php files first is establishing connection to a sql database and and checking if the connection is successfully established so my if statement is in another file and in main file i have an else statment

Comment: like you said i can't do this so its a better idea for me to keep both my if and else statements in a single php file

Comment: @sharan what you are trying to achieve can be done using functions. You can return data from functions and use this response in your if else condition.

Answer (score 1):

The include (or require) statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement.

Including files is very useful when you want to include the same PHP, HTML, or text on multiple pages of a website.

**The include and require statements are identical, except upon failure:**

- require will produce a fatal error (E_COMPILE_ERROR) and stop the script
- include will only produce a warning (E_WARNING) and the script will continue.

So, if you want the execution to go on and show users the output, even if the include file is missing, use the include statement. Otherwise, in case of FrameWork, CMS, or a complex PHP application coding, always use the require statement to include a key file to the flow of execution. This will help avoid compromising your application's security and integrity, just in-case one key file is accidentally missing.

Including files saves a lot of work. This means that you can create a standard header, footer, or menu file for all your web pages. Then, when the header needs to be updated, you can only update the header include file.

**footer.php**

```
<?php
echo "<p>Copyright &copy; 1999-" . date("Y") . " W3Schools.com</p>";
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

[Live Preview](http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_include1)

Source from [PHP 5 Include Files](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

So your code looks like this

```
if($a>$b)
{
  echo $a.' is greater';
}
include "if.php";
else 
{
  echo 'na';
}
```

***Simply Its totally wrong.***

Comment: hahah i read it on w3school but unfortunately not solving my porblem

Comment: use if after include file. So no harm at all